# Updating UIMenuController on the fly

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller

My application has the ability to pop up a menu. When the "Select All" button is pressed, I want to enable the "Delete" button. However I haven't been able to get this working.

Here is a [sample project](http://cl.ly/2j2S0L0d1U2J0k0v3847) illustrating the issue. Run it, then tap the Menu button, press Select All. The Delete button should appear immediately, but it only appears when you hide the menu and then show it again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in iOS 5 (rdar://problem/8819322).

Answer (score 2):

The following does the trick:

```
- (void)didHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
    UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [mc update];
            [mc setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

I've noticed however that it does not work very reliable, for example when setting `animated` to `NO`, the menu is not updated on the fly.

Comment: i tried doing this. I am not able to update the menus. Please help

Comment: I have similar issue with UIMenuController..After tapping on one of the menu option again i want some menu items..so i m using above code.Its working fine in iOS6 but in iOS7 whatever targetFrame i m setting to UIMenuController is not reflecting,its presenting somewhere on the view with improper arrowDirection.