# Menu options not visible after tapping on one of the menu option

Tags: uimenucontroller

I am not able to show other menus on tapping a particular menu option.
The behavior which I want is similar to the default cut-copy menu options that is: When I long press in UITextView area, I get select,select all and other menus. If I tap on select all, immediately i see copy, paste options.

Similar in my app, I have an image on the screen. When I long press the image, I get delete menu. When i tap on delete I should get really delete, cancel menu options.
I am not able to show really delete, cancel options.
Is there any way to do this.
I have come across update method of UIMenucontroller. But don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works.

In your menu item click event, add notification for UIMenuHideNotification and in its handler write follwoing code

```
- (void)didHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
    UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //create a new menu items add it to mc and display it///
            [mc setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: hey, that was my idea! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598456/updating-uimenucontroller-on-the-fly/4599514#4599514

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. It's really helpful. Plus +1 for the answer. I tried out many things and finally saw your ans.

Comment: I have similar issue with UIMenuController..After tapping on one of the menu option again i want some menu items..so i m using above code.Its working fine in iOS6 but in iOS7 whatever targetFrame i m setting to UIMenuController is not reflecting,its presenting somewhere on the view with improper arrowDirection.